# CfCreatePlaceholders returns 0x8007017C

Tags: windows-10, msdn, windows-10-desktop

I'm using the Windows Cloud Filter API to write a sync provider, but my calls to CfCreatePlaceholders are always failing.

Here's an example of the code I run once my provider is all connected:

```
CF_PLACEHOLDER_CREATE_INFO cInfo[1] = { 0 };
cInfo[0].RelativeFileName = L"testfile";
cInfo[0].FsMetadata.BasicInfo.FileAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY;
cInfo[0].Flags = CF_PLACEHOLDER_CREATE_FLAG_NONE;
```

...

```
HRESULT ret = CfCreatePlaceholders(basePath, cInfo, 1, CF_CREATE_FLAG_STOP_ON_ERROR, &EntriesProcessed);
```

I expect CfCreatePlaceholders to return S_OK, but instead it returns 0x8007017C (ERROR_CLOUD_FILE_INVALID_REQUEST). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I asume you create the placeholder in a SyncRoot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I posted my question, I found Microsoft's sample app that demonstrates how to use this API. That sample shows several things that are not clear in the documentaiton.

In case it will help anyone else: [Cloud Mirror Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/CloudMirror)

Comment: So... Microsoft, a sample for Cloud Storage Provider/Sync Root Manager/Cloud Filter/Files On-Demand/On-Demand Sync is now called Cloud Mirror?